# Entity Configurantion: How to properly configure classes and the Entity configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

My question is whether I'm doing the right relationship in classes and in the Entity configuration

Where should I do the 1: n relationship? in the Boat class or InfoAppointment class?
I did it in the InfoAppointment , but I am in doubt.

The InfoWeather It will always be registered along with the InfoAppointment. The InfoWeather is not registered elsewhere, so with each InfoAppointment entry record, i can have an infoWeather, besides the infoWeather can also be optional

I also have doubts in the configuration where it is 0 or 1, right?

My Class `InfoAppointment` can  have only one `Boat`

My `Boat` Class can be in multiple `InfoAppointment`.

My Class `InfoAppointment` can have zero or one `InfoWeather`

My Class `InfoWeather` can have one or zero `InfoAppointment`

```
public  class InfoAppointment : Entity
{
  public Guid Boat_Id { get; set; }
  public virtual Boat Boat { get; set; }
  public virtual InfoWeather infoWeather { get; set; }
}

public  class InfoWeather : Entity
{
  public virtual InfoAppointment InfoAppointment { get; set; }
}

public  class Boat : Entity
{
 public virtual ICollection<InfoAppointment> InfoAppointment { get; set; }
}



public class InfoAppointmentConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<InfoAppointment>
{
  HasRequired(c => c.Boat)
              .WithMany(c => c.InfoAppointment )
              .HasForeignKey(c => c.Boat_Id);

   HasOptional(c => c.InfoWeather )
            .WithOptionalDependent(c => c.InfoAppointment );
}

public class BoatConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Boat>
{
}

public class InfoWeatherConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<InfoWeather >
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are as follows:

> 1. My Class `InfoAppointment` can have only one `Boat`
> 2. My Class `Boat` can be in multiple `InfoAppointment`.
> 3. My Class `InfoAppointment` can have zero or one `InfoWeather`
> 4. My Class `InfoWeather` can have one or zero `InfoAppointment`

Then write the relationship between `InfoAppointment`, `Boat` and `InfoWeather`  as follows:

```
public  class InfoAppointment : Entity
{
  [Key]
  public Guid InfoAppointmentId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("Boat")]
  public Guid BoatId {get; set;}

  // other properties

  public virtual Boat Boat { get; set; }

  public virtual InfoWeather infoWeather { get; set; }
}

public  class Boat : Entity
{
   public Guid BoatId {get; set;}

   // other properties

   public virtual List<InfoAppointment> InfoAppointments { get; set; }
}

public  class InfoWeather : Entity
{
  [Key,ForeignKey("InfoAppointment")]
  public Guid InfoAppointmentId { get; set; }

  // other properties

  public virtual InfoAppointment InfoAppointment { get; set; }
}
```

Till requirement #3 everything is fine. Your fourth requirement

> 4. My Class `InfoWeather` can have one or zero `InfoAppointment`

needs to be sure that you are really wanting this. Then you have to update the `InfoAppointment` and `InfoWeather` entity as follows:

```
public  class InfoAppointment : Entity
{
  public Guid InfoAppointmentId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("Boat")]
  public Guid BoatId {get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("InfoWeather")]
  public Guid InfoWeatherId {get; set;}


  // other properties

  public virtual Boat Boat { get; set; }

  public virtual InfoWeather InfoWeather { get; set; }
}


public  class InfoWeather : Entity
{
  [Key]
  public Guid InfoWeatherId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("InfoAppointment")]
  public Guid InfoAppointmentId { get; set; }

  // other properties

  public virtual InfoAppointment InfoAppointment { get; set; }
}
```

Now have to specify the principal entity with `FluentAPI` as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<InfoAppointment>()
   .HasOptional(x => x.InfoWeather)
   .WithOptionalPrincipal(x => x.InfoAppointment)
   .Map(a => a.MapKey("InfoWeatherId"));
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: When you have 1:M relationship, you put the foreign key on many side and a navigation property on the one side. 

EF framework will create a foreign key simple by using the convention EntityName followed by Id. You do not need to use the EntityTypeConfiguration class. 

On the navigation property side (where the many points to one parent), it can be loaded in Linq Queries by using the Include https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectquery-1.include?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I know this! But I have written this explicitly for readability! Thank you.

Comment: @TanvirArjel  "My Class InfoWeather can have one or zero InfoAppointment". The InfoWeather It will always be registered along with the InfoAppointment. The InfoWeather is not registered elsewhere, so with each InfoAppointment entry record, I can have an infoWeather, besides the infoWeather can also be optional

Comment: @TanvirArjel I ended up putting a wrong information, actually My Class InfoAppointment can have only one Boat

Comment: Okay! Update your question accordingly. I shall modify my answer too.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Update the question with the new informations! with [Edit] tag at new informations

Comment: @Jhensen Check my answer! I have updated my answer!

Comment: @TanvirArjel thx! but i have two questions? the public Guid public Guid InfoWeatherId at InfoAppointment class should be null? since it is optional ? and why WithOptionalPrincipal? I always confuse the WithOptionalPrincipal and WithOptionalDependent

Comment: Test with both and lets see what happen and then differentiate !

Comment: @TanvirArjel ok, thx! One last question. You have configured the fluent api for the InfoAppointment  class, what would change if you configure for the infoWeather class? let's suppose I wanted to fetch the infoWeather of a Appointment, would it be possible regardless of which side I was configured to?